# How to assign multiple csv files to multiple names in a loop in r?

Tags: r, csv

I'm not exactly familiar with R and I'm struggling to write a loop function for this piece of code.
As you can see, there's only the number next to "indice" which changes but I don't know how to do the loop. I have 5 files in total, it's not a lot but I don't want to keep writing over and over the same lines.
Thank you very much and wish you guys a nice day.

```
indice = read.csv("C:/Users/huonn/Desktop/Thèse recherche/data/CAC40.csv");
indice2 = read.csv("C:/Users/huonn/Desktop/Thèse recherche/data/DAX.csv");
indice3 = read.csv("C:/Users/huonn/Desktop/Thèse recherche/data/DJIA.csv");


colnames(indice)
names(indice)[names(indice) == "ï..Date"] <- "Date"
indice$Date <- as.Date(indice$Date,
                       format = "%d/%m/%Y")
indice$Dernier <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", indice$Dernier)))

colnames(indice2)
names(indice2)[names(indice2) == "ï..Date"] <- "Date"
indice2$Date <- as.Date(indice2$Date,
                       format = "%d/%m/%Y")
indice2$Dernier <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", indice2$Dernier)))

colnames(indice3)
names(indice3)[names(indice3) == "ï..Date"] <- "Date"
indice3$Date <- as.Date(indice3$Date,
                        format = "%d/%m/%Y")
indice3$Dernier <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", indice3$Dernier)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` would be helpful here for you.

```
filenames <- list.files('C:/Users/huonn/Desktop/Thèse recherche/data/', full.names = TRUE, pattern = '\\.csv$')

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  indice <- read.csv(x)
  names(indice)[names(indice) == "ï..Date"] <- "Date"
  indice$Date <- as.Date(indice$Date,format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  indice$Dernier <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", indice$Dernier)))
  indice
}) -> result
```

`result` has list of dataframes in it. It is better to keep data in a list instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment (like `indice`, `indice2` etc) which is difficult to manage as the number of csvs grow.